# NgRx Data Service not triggering end point

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-entity

I am trying to setup NgRx Data in sample project. The use case is to fetch Employee entities using Data Service and store them. So I defined data service, collection service and app module as below. I added **All Employees** button on home page which gets all employees in database.
When I click on **All Employees** button, the end point is not being called. It seems I am missing something basic here

**all-employees.component.html**

```
<h1>All Employees</h1>
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let employee of employees$ | async">{{ employee.lastName }}, {{ employee.firstName }}</li>
</ul>
```

**employee-data.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class EmployeeDataService extends DefaultDataService<Employee> {
    constructor(http: HttpClient, httpUrlGenerator: HttpUrlGenerator, logger: Logger) {
        super('Employee', http, httpUrlGenerator);
        logger.log('Created custom Employee EntityDataService');
    }

    override getAll(): Observable<Employee[]> {
        return this.http.get<Employee[]>('http://localhost:3000/employees');
    }
}
```

and employee service like this
**employee.service.ts**

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class EmployeeService extends EntityCollectionServiceBase<Employee> {
    constructor(serviceElementsFactory: EntityCollectionServiceElementsFactory) {
        super('Employee', serviceElementsFactory);
    }
}
```

and AppModule that ties all of these together
**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(
            [
                {
                    path: 'all_employees',
                    component: AllEmployeesComponent,
                },
            ],
            { initialNavigation: 'enabledBlocking' }
        ),
        StoreModule.forRoot(reducers, {
            metaReducers: !environment.production ? [] : [],
            runtimeChecks: {
                strictActionImmutability: true,
                strictStateImmutability: true,
            },
        }),
        EntityDataModule.forRoot({
            entityMetadata: appEntityMetadata,
        }),
        EffectsModule.forRoot([]),
        !environment.production ? StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument() : [],
        StoreRouterConnectingModule.forRoot(),
    ],
    providers: [EmployeeDataService],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {
    constructor(entityDataService: EntityDataService, EmployeeDataService: EmployeeDataService) {
        entityDataService.registerService('Employee', EmployeeDataService);
    }
}
```

**Code:**
The code uploaded to [Github](https://github.com/pavankjadda/nx-projects/tree/main/apps/ngrx-demo) and run it by following the below instructions

1. Clone the repo and install dependencies
2. Start the sample JSON server

```
json-server --watch db.json
```

3. Run the project

```
nx serve ngrx-demo
```

Comment: Can you add the html code to see how you're handling the data and what is the button calling?

Comment: @FlorenciaCames see the updated post

Answer (score 2):

Edit:
Ok, this is pretty hard to detect, but actually the order of declaration in the NgModule matters. I compared with one of my project and found that `EntityDataModule` is loaded the last, after both :

- StoreModule
- EffectsModule

```js
EffectsModule.forRoot([]),
!environment.production ? StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument() : [],
StoreRouterConnectingModule.forRoot(),
EntityDataModule.forRoot(entityConfig),
```

This makes sense but it was tricky !
And also, be careful with naming your services, I would advice not to use Uppercase for the first letter of your instance :
`employeeDataService: EmployeeDataService`

---

Maybe I missed something in your code, but I don't see the place where you actually ask the service to retreive the Entities. From my experience you not only need to create an Observable from the adapter, but you need to call one of the built-in method of NgRx Data like :

https://ngrx.io/guide/data

```js
getHeroes() {
    this.heroService.getAll();
  }
```

It should happen here : https://github.com/pavankjadda/nx-projects/blob/main/apps/ngrx-demo/src/app/all-employees/all-employees.component.ts

So, if I'm not wrong you simply add this call and your endpoint should be triggered !
Cheers.

Alain

Comment: That was my first modification, it didn't work. See updated code line [here](https://github.com/pavankjadda/nx-projects/blob/main/apps/ngrx-demo/src/app/all-employees/all-employees.component.ts#L18=)

Comment: I edited the answer, tell me if it works for you !

Comment: I updated the code, still the same issue

Comment: Check my fork here, it works : https://github.com/aboudard/nx-projects. I fixed the entityMetadata too.

Comment: I got it working without your changes. The only problem, the external API being hit every time instead of using cache after first fetch. You can see the changes [here](https://github.com/pavankjadda/nx-projects/blob/main/apps/ngrx-demo/src/app/all-employees/all-employees.component.ts#L15=)

Comment: I'm glad it works. But you're not supposed to use the `getAll()` method to retreive the entities, you should use one of the inner Observables like `entities$`. And to my knowledge, there is no built-in Http cache strategy in NgRx Data, did you mean the use of the Store ? If you don't want to call the `getAll()` method too often, simply put this call at a higher level of your application.

Comment: I am trying to cache entity data. Store in cache on initial load/cache miss and load from cache on subsequent calls. Don't know why is it so difficult in NgRx (unless I am doing something wrong here)

Comment: Well it's not specifically difficult, but it's not how it works. When you work with your Store, it won't make any request unless you want it to, so don't call `getAll()` when you don't need it, and the rest of the time, use the built-in `Observables` exposed by the lib. NgRx Data is simply making easy to map endpoints with Store Entities.